# How can I update or create the Redis Cache data in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, redis, lumen

For my project, I want to use Redis caching for higher performance of data fetching.

I've 7 million data in my table and that data is very dynamic. It is changing in every second. We have background scripts to change (create new data or update existing data) based on certain condition. Based on unread data I need to sort it based on user specific data and get first 50/100 records based on unread data plus few certain conditions.

In my system those data are updated/created every hour and based on that latest data I have to show listing to the user on frontend.

So how can I manage the Redis caching in this situation with updated data on every page refresh?

Comment: *"So how can I manage the Redis caching in this situation with updated data on every page refresh?"* - if the data is changing on every request, is it really cacheable?

Comment: Are you running into a performance problem, is that why you want to go with Redis? Or are you hoping that this will just make things faster?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yeah correct, because of performance problem, I want to use Redis Caching.

Comment: In my systems where I need "refresh" something  expensive I move all of that logic over to a CLI tool that I run through cron. That gives me the ability to run whenever and debug to console. But since my CLI is integrated into my app, I can also update app variables to either point people to a new location or force a cache refresh. The cache itself can be the results of the "worst" query (longest running, most CPU, memory, etc.) and even better it can be the transformed result (after PHP). Whatever is refreshing can then point the app to the freshest data.